# PDF to JPG with PHP unexpected behaviour

Tags: php, pdf, jpeg, imagick

I'm using Imagick to convert all pages in a PDF to JPGs. But something is off, probably because of my lack of PDF knowledge.

**The problem**
The PDF I'm converting is a book. All pages turns out great except the cover page/first page. If I open the pdf in a PDF previewer it looks as it should but my converted image displays the cover page + a backside of the book. If I open the first page of the PDF in Illustrator I get the same result as my image. I also have a problem with some pdf's containing margins which is not displayed in a PDF previewer but as whitespace in my images.

[image]

But when converted to an image, the backside is white. It's like it doesn't exist but the image dimensions equals both of them.

**Cause and Solution**
Why does this happen and can I ignore the back somehow? Or should this be fixed in the PDF? Shit in shit out...

**Code example**

```
//...
$imagick->readImage('book.pdf[0]');
//...
file_put_contents('cover.jpg', $imagick):
```

---

**Possible solution**
Seems like if I use `trimImage` I get the expected result. So I have a bonus question. How does `trimImage` work? How does it know what to trim, let's say for example if I have a white image with text in the middle?

Comment: Could you please share a PDF document that shows this behaviour?

Comment: I can try to create a similar effect but i can't share the books I currently have

Comment: If trimImage resets it, it would be interesting to test what `$imagick->setImagePage($imagick->getImageWidth, $imagick->getImageHeight(), 0, 0);` does.

Comment: Hm yeah, will definitely try that. Very interesting, it will either result in a white box or magically fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this and the solution was really simple. The solution is to use **cropbox**. You can set Imagick options by using [setOption](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setoption.php).

```
$imagick->setOption('pdf:use-cropbox', 'true');
```

Available options can be found here: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php